# When Using POST method to call API i get error (Fatal no Params)

Tags: c#, curl, httpwebrequest

When i use cURL to Post to my API, it works 100%, i have build a desktop application in C# that needs to the same when a button is clicked. when i capture my code through fiddler it shows that is connects successfully but gives me this error:
{"fatal":"No POST params!"}

when i use Postman to test i get the same error:

{"fatal":"No POST params!"}

this is my cURL script that works:

curl  -u  username:"password" -X POST http://localhost/api/index.php -d method="addSubscriber" -d first_name="test" -d last_name="account" -d address="980 westlane, Khomasdal" -d postcode="999 Windhoek" -d country="Namibia" -d email="test@gmail.com" -d mobile_number="26487222225" -d package[package_uid][]="live" -d package[package_uid][]="timeshift" -d package[valid_from][]="2018-05-24" -d package[valid_from][]="2018-05-24" -d package[duration][]="31" -d package[duration][]="31"

this is my code in C#: where i am using HttpWebRequest:

```
        HttpWebRequest webRequest;
        webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost/api/index.php");
        String authHeaer = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(userName + ":" + userPassword));

        webRequest.Method = "POST";
        webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        string requestParams = "{\"method\" : \"addSubscriber\",\"first_name\" : '"+txt_fname.Text+"', \"last_name\" : \"'"+txt_lname.Text+"'\", \"address\":\"default\", \"postcode\":\"0000\", \"country\" : \"Namibia\", \"email\" :\"'"+txt_email.Text+"'\", \"mobile_number\" : \"'"+txt_cellno.Text+"'\", \"package_uid\" : \"live\", \"package_valid_from\" : \"'"+DateTime.Now+"'\", \"package_duration\" : \"'"+txtDuration.Text+"'\"}"; //format information you need to pass into that string ('info={ "EmployeeID": [ "1234567", "7654321" ], "Salary": true, "BonusPercentage": 10}');
        webRequest.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = "Basic " + authHeaer;
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestParams);
        webRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        using (Stream requestStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream())
        {
            requestStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        }

        // Get the response.
        using (WebResponse response = webRequest.GetResponse())
        {
            using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
                string Json = rdr.ReadToEnd(); // response from server

            }
        }

        MessageBox.Show("Client Added Succesfully");
```

Comment: `WebRequest.Create("http://localhostapi/index.php")` doesn't look correct. It also looks like you're wrapping some of your json values in single quotes. If you're sending to a service that requires the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` contenttype, JSON isn't going to work, you'll need to convert it to a urlencoded data string.

Comment: when i use json as content type it gives me the error fatal no params!, when i use the (x-www-form-urlencoded) as content type i get, the method does not exist.

Comment: I think there should be a problem with my format: "{\"method\" : \"addSubscriber\",\"first_name\" : '"+txt_fname.Text+"', \"last_name\" : \"'"+txt_lname.Text+"'\", \"address\":\"default\", \"postcode\":\"0000\", \"country\" : \"Namibia\", \"email\" :\"'"+txt_email.Text+"'\", \"mobile_number\" : \"'"+txt_cellno.Text+"'\", \"package_uid\" : \"live\", \"package_valid_from\" : \"'"+DateTime.Now+"'\", \"package_duration\" : \"'"+txtDuration.Text+"'\"}";

Answer (score 0):

I changed my content type from json to urlencoded, and changed the format of a  bit, and i could get the desired output i wanted.

Here is the new code below:

HttpWebRequest webRequest;
            webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://197.188.246.11/megatel/api/v1/index.php");
            String authHeaer = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(userName + ":" + userPassword));

```
        webRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;
        //"POST";
        webRequest.Accept= "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"; 
        webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        string requestParams = "method=addSubscriber&first_name=" + txt_fname.Text +"&last_name=" + txt_lname.Text + "&address=" + txt_City.Text + "&postcode=" + txt_POBOX.Text + "&country=Brazil&email=" + txt_email.Text + "&mobile_number=" + txt_cellno.Text + "&package%5Bpackage_uid%5D%5B%5D=live&package%5Bpackage_uid%5D%5B%5D=timeshift&package%5Bvalid_from%5D%5B%5D=" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "&package%5Bvalid_from%5D%5B%5D=" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "&package%5Bduration%5D%5B%5D=" + txtDuration.Text + "&package%5Bduration%5D%5B%5D=" + txtDuration.Text + "";
        webRequest.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = "Basic " + authHeaer;
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestParams);
        webRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        using (Stream requestStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream())
        {
            requestStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        }

        // Get the response.

        using (WebResponse response = webRequest.GetResponse())
        {
            using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(responseStream,Encoding.UTF8);
                string Json = rdr.ReadToEnd();

            }
        }
```